# calculate canvas context.setTransform matrix based on a 4x4 matrix

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix, 3d

I am trying to simulate 3d rotation of a bitmap using javascript and html5 canvas (without webGL). I think the way to go is to compute the terms for the 2D matrix of the canvas context.setTransform method, but I can't figure out how to obtain that matrix ideally from a general 4x4 matrix representing the desired transformation or the desired final position of the bitmap in pixels (I can compute the desired final coordinates in pixels projecting the corners with the 4x4 matrix and the project-view matrix).

in this fiddle I had been playing with manipulating a couple of angles (representing the rotation of a 3d camera with two degrees of freedom) to calculate shear terms for the setTransform matrix, but I really can't obtain a clear insight of the ideal procedure to follow. http://jsfiddle.net/cesarpachon/GQvp2/

```
context.save();
        /*alpha affects the scaley with sin
        */
         var skew = Math.sin(alpha);

         var scalex = 1;//(1-skew) +0.01;//Math.sin(alpha);
         var scaley = 1;//Math.abs(Math.sin(alpha))+0.01; 
        var offx = 0;
        var offy = 0;
        var skewx = Math.sin(alpha);
        var skewy = Math.sin(beta);
          context.setTransform(scalex,skewx,skewy,scaley,offx,offy);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, height, width); 
context.restore();
```

Comment: A complete tutorial on simulating 3d transforms with a 2d context is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question.  Here's a starting point with quite a few techniques you will find helpful in gaining your understanding of 3d perspective:  http://ajaxian.com/archives/tricks-from-our-flash-friends-3d-in-a-2d-context

Comment: maybe I can describe better my problem as "infering projective mappings from 2d quadrilaters", ie: how to calculate the canvas context.setTransform matrix so the picture stretches to a predefined shape. (the fact that the coordinates of the desired shape had been obtained through 3d transform is not relevant)thks!

Answer (score 1):

A severe limitation when projecting 3d into 2d is that the 2d transforms only use an affine matrix.

This means any 2d transform will always result in a parallelogram.

3d perspectives most often require at least a trapezoidal result (not achievable in affine transforms).

**Bottom line:** You can't consistently get 3d perspective from 2d transforms.

One workaround is to use image slicing to fit an image into 3d coordinates

http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/image-manipulation-html5-canvas102.html

Another more mathematically intense workaround is to map an image onto perspective triangles:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerspectiveTriangles.html

Good luck with your project! :-)